# Extracting specific string matches from a Stock Website page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying webscrape stock market caps, using this below code.
At first I traditionally tried to fetch the list of `market cap values` using bs4.
When I used  `print(x.find('span',{'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'}).text)` to do this, I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` error.

```
  for x in marketCapArray:
        print(x.find('span',{'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'}).text)
```

I did not know how to resolve the above error specific to my code. So I took an alternative using regex to simply extract the required values and tried this below.

**Main Code**

```
import bs4
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def pickTopGainers():
  url =  'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/gainers?offset=0&count=100'
  page = urlopen(url)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
  marketCapArray = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)',
 'aria-label': 'Market cap'})
  print(str(marketCapArray))
  xi = re.findall("........</span>", str(marketCapArray)) # regex-use-1
  pi = re.sub("(</span>|....>N/A|>|\")","", str(xi))
  print(pi)

pickTopGainers()
```

**Results**

This is what `print(str(marketCapArray)` would output. (pasted only some part)

```
[<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="93"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s)" data-reactid="94">159.404M</span></td>, 
<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="119"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s)" data-reactid="120">533.97M</span></td>, 
<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="145"><span data-reactid="146">N/A</span></td>, 
<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="171"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s)" data-reactid="172">2.952B</span></td>, 
<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="197"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s)" data-reactid="198">9.223B</span></td>, 
<td aria-label="Market cap" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Pend(10px) W(120px) Fz(s)" colspan="" data-reactid="223"><span data-reactid="224">N/A</span></td>]
```

This is the output of `print(pi)`. Also the final output.

```
['159.404M', '533.97M', '', '2.952B', '9.223B', '']
```

---

### Question

How can I avoid using regex replace(re.sub) in the above `Main Code` to achieve the given final output `pi` ?
or Suggest me the right approach to do this. I feel my regex is unpleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate row by row inside the `<table>`, where all information is stored. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/gainers?offset=0&count=100'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

fmt_string = '{:<15} {:<60} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'
print(fmt_string.format('Symbol', 'Name', 'Price(int)', 'Change', '% change', 'Volume', 'AvgVol(3M)', 'Market Cap', 'PE ratio'))
for row in soup.select('table:has(a[href*="/quote/"]) > tbody > tr'):
    cells = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(fmt_string.format(*cells[:-1]))
```

Prints:

```
Symbol          Name                                                         Price(int) Change     % change   Volume     AvgVol(3M) Market Cap PE ratio  
CCCL.NS         Consolidated Construction Consortium Limited                 0.2000     +0.0500    +33.33%    57,902     290,154    159.404M   N/A       
KSERASERA.NS    KSS Limited                                                  0.2500     +0.0500    +25.00%    1.607M     2.601M     533.97M    N/A       
BONLON.BO       BONLON INDUSTRIES LIMITED                                    21.60      +3.60      +20.00%    16,000     N/A        N/A        N/A       
MENONBE.NS      Menon Bearings Limited                                       52.80      +8.80      +20.00%    2.334M     65,713     2.952B     25.05     
RPOWER.NS       Reliance Power Limited                                       3.3000     +0.5500    +20.00%    127.814M   18.439M    9.223B     N/A       
11DPD.BO        Nippon India Mutual Fund                                     0.0600     +0.0100    +20.00%    190        N/A        N/A        N/A       
ABFRLPP-E1.NS   Aditya Birla Rs.5 ppd up                                     105.65     +17.60     +19.99%    1.238M     N/A        N/A        N/A       
500110.BO       Chennai Petroleum Corporation Limited                        64.55      -0.15      -0.23%     42,765     61,584     9.612B     N/A       
ABFRLPP.BO      Aditya Birla Fashion and Retai                               106.05     +17.65     +19.97%    387,703    N/A        N/A        N/A       
RADIOCITY.NS    Music Broadcast Limited                                      21.35      +3.55      +19.94%    12.657M    1.013M     7.38B      124.13    
RADIOCITY.BO    Music Broadcast Limited                                      21.35      +3.55      +19.94%    898,070    90,236     7.38B      124.13    
MENONBE.BO      Menon Bearings Limited                                       52.65      +8.75      +19.93%    137,065    8,648      2.951B     24.98     
MTNL.BO         Mahanagar Telephone Nigam Limited                            10.72      +1.78      +19.91%    1.142M     156,275    6.754B     N/A       

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better to work with. However, is it possible to extract the values of this table printed, separately . Like each row as a dictionary so that I could facilitate some arthemetics on it.

Comment: @Thinker-101 You can do, for example `print( cells[7] )` to print just Market Capitalization. You can store it inside list for example etc..